# How to remove certain character from a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector, for example, `c(21,34,"99*",56,"90*", "45*")`. I need to clean the data using R by transforming this into a vector without the extra `*`. The result in this example should be `c(21,34,99,56,90,45)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the `*` by specifying `fixed = TRUE` as it is a metacharacter that denotes zero or more characters.  In addition to `fixed = TRUE`, it can be escaped (`\\*`) or place inside square brackets (`[*]`) to get the literal meaning of `*`

```
as.numeric( sub("*", "", v1, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] 21 34 99 56 90 45
```

---

A convenient function would be `parse_number` from `readr`

```
readr::parse_number(v1)
#[1] 21 34 99 56 90 45
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(21,34,"99*",56,"90*", "45*")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method gsub .

```
a =c(21,34,"99*",56,"90*", "45*") 
gsub("\\*","",a)


# result [1] "21" "34" "99" "56" "90" "45"
```

Comment: @akrun slight difference , add more than one * for a number , sub will replace only 1 * , gsub does a global replace . your and mine are equally right.